# XCTest: Crashing in XCTestExpectations in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestexpectation

When I run my unit test scripts, it is crashing at ""waitForExpectationWithTimeout" in "ServiceTest" class.

**If I run test scripts for this "ServiceTest" class alone, then it is working properly without crash.** But if I run test scripts for entire project, I am getting this crash. I am clueless on why and what this crash means. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590830/xctestcase-waitforexpectationswithtimeouthandler-throwing-exc-bad-access-when

Comment: I am passing expectation value as "High" and not nil. "expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("High")"

Comment: In that case, there is too little code to diagnose this problem. You could have a nil or Unsafe type anywhere.